# How do I give permissions to a client when using a TLS connection?

Tags: security, authentication, ssl, certificate, authorization

I'm using TLS to authenticate clients logging into my server.

I would like to set up some role-based access so that when they log-in, they can only access certain information based on their role.

What is the best way to accomplish this? Can you specify the role when you create the client certificate? Do you do it based on some other attribute of the client?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You *could* put the role info into the certificate (as a custom X.509v3 Extension), but then if you ever need to change their role, then you need to revoke and re-issue the certificate. That seems like a headache.

Better would be to treat "Authentication" and "Authorization" separately. Use the certificate as "Authentication"; ie the certificate proves that they are the user listed in the DN and SANs, then you look up that DN in an "Authorization" service / database that tells you what permissions that user should have. If you want to get really fancy, the authorization service could return a signed JWT with their username/DN and permissions, sorta like a custom SAML/OIDC claim.

As a bonus, this system will scale nicely if you decide to add alternative authentication methods in the future such as API keys, MFA, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response. If I went with option 1, the role would go into the issued client certificate?

Comment: Yes. You'll need to play with your CA to figure out how to insert custom certificate extensions, and play with your X.509 library to figure out how to read them.